# how to use distinct keyword to filter object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

i have a project list where i can get all details about projects. In project class,i have object of customer in project ,  i just want to filter that list according to customer. how can i do this .

```
public ICollection<Project> GetProjectBasicDetailsByProjectTypeCustomerID(ProjectType projectType, string custName, string cordinatorName, string projectName)
    {
        oLog.Debug("Started");
        ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenReaderSession();
        ITransaction transaction = null;
        ICollection<Project> projectList = null;
        try
        {
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Project),"Project")
                .CreateAlias("Project.customer","customer",NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .CreateAlias("Project.Coordinator", "Coordinator", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Project.ProjectType", projectType));


            projectList = criteria.List<Project>().ToList();

            session.Flush();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();
            oLog.Error(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Dispose();

            if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                session.Close();
        }
        oLog.Debug("End");
        return projectList;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please some code, the controller action, the filtering logic etc.? Because based on your current description it's hard to help.

Comment: @nemesv i have post the service used by me... Here i want to filter list based on customer, not project...

Comment: Chapter 15 of the NHibernate reference deals with the Criteria API, section 15.4 in particular deals with associations: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations Have you tried this? What exactly is it that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you would like to get the distinct customers from your projects ?

In this case I think something like this should work (this should give you the dictinct project IDs from this criteria - maybe there is a way to get the projects directly - but I can't test this right now:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Project),"Project")
                .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("project.Id")))
                .CreateAlias("Project.customer","customer",NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .CreateAlias("Project.Coordinator", "Coordinator", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Project.ProjectType", projectType));
```